# Magento 2 How to add custom class to the country and state select box container in all forms in the frontend?

Tags: magento2, shipping-address, billing-address, checkout-page

I need to add a custom class to the country and state select box container in all forms expecially in shipping and billing address form on frontend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open file or override checkout

`vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml`

search for the line `<item name=”country_id” xsi:type=”array”>`  and

add class `<item name="class" xsi:type="string">the-class</item>`

Answer (score 0):

add class at checkout page

**VendorNameSpace\Module\etc\di.xml**

```
<type name="Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger">
    <plugin name="customAttributeMerger" type="VendorNameSpace\Module\Plugin\AttributeMergerPlugin"/>
</type>
```

**AttributeMergerPlugin.php VendorNameSpace\Module\Plugin**

```
<?php
namespace VendorNameSpace\Module\Plugin;

class AttributeMergerPlugin
{
    public function afterMerge(\Magento\Checkout\Block\Checkout\AttributeMerger $subject, $result)
    {
        // add Additional class for country
        if (array_key_exists('country_id', $result)) {
              $result['country_id']['additionalClasses'] = 'custom-class-country';
        }
        // add Additional class for city
        if (array_key_exists('city', $result)) {
            $result['city']['additionalClasses'] = 'cusotom-city';
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

**Hope this will help you. thanks**

Comment: By doing this you would affect all elements with this id. I believe the correct approach is to extend LayoutProcessor block (with a Plugin) and use AttributeMerger there to change the node you want to.